# Rails: Method to integrate Facebook in future versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication

I am working on a Rails-version of a website where I have already created a login-structure using **authlogic** as login. The reason for chosing it is that I have used it for my other three Rails-websites, but why I started with it I can't remember.

My web application would be way better off with a Facebook-login and other types of integrations with Facebook but it is not crucial for the MVP. In order to have a quicker launch and push the whole learning-and-implementing effort to the future I am considering to push this Facebook-integration to 2.0. I am still but of a novice and it all seems quite complicated.

My major issue with this, however, is that I don't want to end up in a situation where I can't combine the two in the future. I am afraid this will mean that I will have to have two parallell set of users.

Today I am using a User-table with information like: user_name, id (i.e. the Rails row id), full name, birth date etc. I would like, in the future, the user to be able to login using Facebook instead and tie it to his old account. I am using the user.id as the connection between all the other tables in the application (comments, questions asked, ideas etc).

A. Would integration with Facebook be possible the way I am planning to do or am I creating an even larger problem for the future doing it like this?

B. Should I refrain from using *authlogic* here (and in general as well perhaps)? Using *omniauth* or *devise* (as I have been recommended) would take some time and effort and I already have a working login system, but if it is a strong recommendation, I will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Add Ons section](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/#authlogic-%E2%80%9Cadd-ons%E2%80%9D) of authlogic.

There are few plugins for facebook connect, for example [Authlogic Facebook Shim](https://github.com/james2m/authlogic_facebook_shim)

---

You should notice That if we compare github statistics of [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/graphs) and [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/graphs) the first one is much more active project (look at commits). So I recommend moving to devise if your project is at the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks, but it is this a good way to go? If worst come to worst, can I change the authentication method to e.g. omniauth but keep the user-tables and passwords?

Comment: Don't worry authlogic have good community you always get help with implementing authlogic related features. But read my edit about projects activity.